# jQuery jCarousel - Justifying items within horizontal viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jcarousel

I am having issues with my jcarousel installation.  Currently how I have it set up is three items in a row with a viewport of 1140px.  jcarousel automatically adjusts these items and sets them to 380px wide each to fit the viewport properly.  The margin-right seems automatically defined as well.  I am having an issue justifying my three items evenly within the viewport.  I've looked through the jcarousel options though didn't find anything that might help.  Here is a screenshot that should explain my issue:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GBI0.jpg

Edit: I found a solution, the only thing I'm able to come up with.  If anybody knows of a better solution please post!

My page is based on an 1140 responsive grid system.  In my grid system the right margin for a three column row is ~3.8% and the width per column is ~30%.  So for my carousel's horizontal viewport (.jcarousel-clip-horizontal) I set it's width to 103.8% rather then 100%, this allows for the three items to expand equally across the page container.

I was trying to adjust margins and paddings on individual items but that was incorrect.  At first I placed a left padding on the carousel container to give it a centered appearance, but that wasn't sufficient for my responsive layout.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the width jcarousel automatically does you can set it yourself in the setupCallback:function(){} with the jcarousel setup

for example: you want to set each li with the width 375, you can do this:

```
$('#a').jcarousel({
        visible:3,
        scroll:3,
        setupCallback:function(){
           $('#a.jcarousel-list li').each(function(){
                $(this).width(375)
           })
        },
})
```

you can modify padding/margin on each item or on the viewport with setupCallback:function(){} to achieve what you want.

Comment: Well my idea was to not have to hard-code anything in, I thought maybe jcarousel had a function that calculates how much adjustment is needed between widths, margins, and items shown to expand across the full viewport.  The page I am working on is responsive so I am trying to keep things as flexible as possible while maintaining proper structure that way I don't find myself writing unneeded code to be mobile compatible

Comment: unfortunately jcarousel does not have the support you asked for in config, but it did supports you to achieve what ever you want in callbacks, and sometimes you may find yourself have to use them.